# iOS 10 timezone format trouble with dates created as timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, dateformatter

Before I file a radar I would like to doublecheck if I am not missing something (and learn from this). Here is my test code from a Swift 3 playground (code behaves the same in my app). I am currently working in the timezone "Europe/Lisbon" which in February is the same as GMT.

```
import UIKit

let date =  Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

print(TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!) // GMT

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
print(formatter.string(from: date)) // 01:00

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
print(formatter.string(from: date)) // 00:00

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")
print(formatter.string(from: date)) // 01:00

formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Los_Angeles")
print(formatter.string(from: date)) // 16:00
```

Somehow the formatted time is one hour off except when I set the Timezone as

```
TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT())
```

Is this expected behavior? Thanks!

Comment: I had similar problem with dates. My problem was caused by the formatter not by the time zone. NSDate or Date in Swift works only with UTC. The formatters are responsible for the representation. In my case I had to set the calendar property of the formatter to Gregorian and everything worked as expected from there on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are in fact correct, because in the year 1970 the "Europe/Lisbon" timezone was "UTC+1":

```
let tz = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Lisbon")!

print(tz.secondsFromGMT())
// Output: 0

print(tz.secondsFromGMT(for: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)))
// Output: 3600
```

so that midnight on "Jan 1, 1970 GMT" was one o'clock in the morning
in Lisbon.

You can lookup the timezones and daylight saving time periods
for past and future years at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/portugal/lisbon.

Comment: Hi @martin-r , so does that means that using `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: X)` in tests is dangerous? Looks like the only way to make "timezone-agnostic" timestamp is using date components?

Comment: @Vladimir: What exactly do you mean by "dangerous"? `Date` is an absolute point in time (stored internally as seconds since 1 Jan  2000, UTC) and has no timezone/calendar/... information. – `DateComponents` is a struct containing integers for year, month, day, ... and only becomes a *date* when interpreted in the context of a calendar (and a timezone). – So it depends on what you want to test.

Comment: @MartinR you right. I was confused about the fact that Date is UTC but Gregorian calendar by default is "local time".